# Xcode stops recognizing installed Cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am currently working on an iPhone app using Xcode 11.3.1 (Swift 5) running on a Catalina virtual machine. Periodically, when I build I will get errors that Xcode can't find modules that it had no trouble finding a few minutes ago. If I close the workspace and re-open, Xcode says it's indexing. Most of the time this fixes the problem. Sometimes I have close/re-open more than once.

The modules that I've had trouble with are GoogleSignIn and iOSDropDown. I also have Firebase installed, but so far I haven't seen the error from that one.

I have deleted derived data, and deintegrated/reinstalled my cocoapods. Since I closed the workspace to do both of those the problem was fixed temporarily, but returned.

Doing a clean build (shift-cmd-K) does not fix the problem.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening or at least how I can force a re-index (assuming that's what fixes things temporarily) without closing the workspace?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update: I had been working on a branch in git. I recently merged my branch back into the master and this problem stopped happening. I have no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try: go to your podfile, then there's a line use_frameworks! make that a comment I assume this would solve your issue.